# Фоновый режим в iOs

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане!
Возник такой вопрос, можно ли в iOs сделать так, чтобы программа работала в фоновом режим и ОС не убивала это процесс после закрытия программы?

Уточню сразу, под закрытием программы я понимаю, когда пользователь её закрывает, не сворачивает, а именно закрывает.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, так сделать нельзя. Кроме того, достичь такого невозможно даже в случае сворачивания.

Answer (score 2):

В iOS все просто, у вас **либо работает приложение на background-е, либо нет**, по-другому нельзя.

Comment: А тогда по какому принципу работают программы "Найти Друзей", "Найти Айфон", ведь после разрешения слежения, я могу наблюдать за ними в реальном времени и им не нужно, чтобы программа была всё врем в оперативной памяти или висела в фоне, она может быть закрыта(именно закрыта). К тому же данные программы обладают именно тем функционалом, который мне нужен. Никто не знает как это реализовать?

Comment: Программы "Найти Друзей"  и "Найти iPhone" системные, им подчиняться ограничениям распространяемого для сторонних разработчиков SDK не обязательно.